# How to disable default extension validation in Drupal's #managed_file Form API element?

Tags: files, forms

I wrote validation function that tests file's mimetype. I commented out my old validators to avoid validation by extension:

```
'DownloadFile' => array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t("Download"),
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  //'#description' => t('Allowed extensions: pdf zip exe.'),
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    //'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf zip exe'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('mymodule_image_size', 2 * 1024 * 1024)),
  ),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://mymodule/download',
  '#default_value' => $item->DownloadFile,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#theme' => 'preview_upload',
),
```

Now when I'm trying to upload exe, I get:

> The specified file putty.exe could not be uploaded. Only files with the following extensions are allowed: jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp.

Now, I will have files without extensions there. And with extensions I cannot predict. And all I want sometimes is to test for a proper MIME type match, not even an exact mimetypes sometimes. So, how can I get rid of extension validation and turn it into "everything goes"?

I managed to find [issue](https://drupal.org/node/1864726) that seemed to be about this problem, but it tells to `unset($element['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions']);` - does not make sense to me as I'm creating brand new array and this isn't set at all.

I tried to use `#process` property to add a function that will unset default validators later, like shown there in issue,  but `dpr($element)` shows there is nothing to unset:

```
[#upload_validators] => Array
    (
        [file_validate_size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2097152
            )

    )
```

Comment: I remember this - `file_save_upload()` is to blame, but I can't remember how I got around it

Comment: @Clive To be honest I expected you or other of the experienced users to simply vote it a duplicate. I remember this problem reappears, but cannot find a solution that works. @ ALL if hacking core is the only way (you know), so be it. I'm open about that if I have to. Just please help me do it safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer comes from the following code used by [file_save_upload()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7).

```
  if (isset($validators['file_validate_extensions'])) {
    if (isset($validators['file_validate_extensions'][0])) {
      // Build the list of non-munged extensions if the caller provided them.
      $extensions = $validators['file_validate_extensions'][0];
    }
    else {
      // If 'file_validate_extensions' is set and the list is empty then the
      // caller wants to allow any extension. In this case we have to remove the
      // validator or else it will reject all extensions.
      unset($validators['file_validate_extensions']);
    }
  }
  else {
    // No validator was provided, so add one using the default list.
    // Build a default non-munged safe list for file_munge_filename().
    $extensions = 'jpg jpeg gif png txt doc xls pdf ppt pps odt ods odp';
    $validators['file_validate_extensions'] = array();
    $validators['file_validate_extensions'][0] = $extensions;
  }
```

In your case you should use the following array.

```
  'DownloadFile' => array(
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array(),
      'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('mymodule_image_size', 2 * 1024 * 1024)),
    ),
  );
```

In that way `$validators['file_validate_extensions']` is set, but `$validators['file_validate_extensions'][0]` is not. As result, the code will not set `$extensions`, and the following code will not be executed either.

```
  if (!empty($extensions)) {
    // Munge the filename to protect against possible malicious extension hiding
    // within an unknown file type (ie: filename.html.foo).
    $file->filename = file_munge_filename($file->filename, $extensions);
  }
```

The code has a strange way to check if the list is empty; it assumes the array is empty of there isn't an item with index equal to 0. 
I would have rather used the following one, which would not make assumptions about the lower array index being used.

```
  if (isset($validators['file_validate_extensions'])) {
    if (empty($validators['file_validate_extensions'])) {
      // If 'file_validate_extensions' is set and the list is empty then the
      // caller wants to allow any extension. In this case we have to remove the
      // validator or else it will reject all extensions.
      unset($validators['file_validate_extensions']);
    }
    else {
      // Build the list of non-munged extensions if the caller provided them.
      $extensions = array_shift($validators['file_validate_extensions']);
    }
  }
```